# AIX synchronize directory

Tags: aix, synchronization

I am trying to copy a lot of folders to another directory. I used `cp -R` command to copy them from source to destination. After all the copying was finished, I found that when I was copying, some files were added to the source directory and the copying action was finished.

Say there are 20000 files in the source directory and 19999 files in the destination: how can I copy the missing one without copying them all over again?

Is there a smarter way?

I tried `rsync`, but ksh said there is no rsync.

Answer (score 2):

rsync is in the [AIX Toolbox for Linux Applications](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/aix/linux/toolbox/alpha.html)

You can download the RPM and install it using normal rpm commands.